# Understanding Modulo $(p^n)$ calculation by Binary method

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I wanted to find $2^{133}\equiv -5\mod 133$
I know by calculating some power trick we can simplifies thing but
 I encountered In Number Theory by Jones book ABove can be find using binary method I tried to understand but not get 
that.[image]

[image]

Please Help me to understand above

Comment: What do you **not** understand? This is just a formal description of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation

Comment: @gammatester I do not understand how to obtain 1,2,4,16,-10,-33,50,-27,-5. I read that articles but still I can write in product form but unable to get how to obtain above.

Comment: Start with $x_0=1$, apply $x_1=2x_0^2$ ($g$) so $x_1=2$, apply $x_2=x_1^2$ ($f$) so $x_2=4$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Left-to-right_binary_method: if a bit is $1$ apply $f=x^2 \bmod {133}$ else apply
$g=ax^2 \bmod {133}$. The binary representation of $133$ is $10000101$. Here are the single steps for computation, where the $x$ values are reduced modulo $133$ to give the smallest residue (e.g. $100=-33 \pmod {133}$):

```
Bit  Op    x     
           1
1    g     1^2 * 2 = 2
0    f     2^2 = 4
0    f     4^2 = 16
0    f     16^2 = 256 = 123 = -10
0    f     (-10)^2 = 100 = -33 
1    g     2*(-33)^2 = 2178 = 50
0    f     50^2 = 2500 = 106 = -27
1    g     2*(-27)^2 = 1458 = 128 = -5
```